# Your device isn't compatible with this version - Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I am the developer of an app, I have published the APK to the Play Store's Internal Testing channel. I added the Google account of test device B to the email list. For some reason, it shows 'your device isn't compatible with this version' when I try to install my app from the Play Store. I can sideload the APK generated by Android Studio without any problems...

I can install the app from the Play Store on my Galaxy Note 20 Ultra (test device A) but not on my Zebra TC26. Even though the device catalog in the Google Play Console shows the device is compatible with my app.

What's going on here?

Comment: If you can side-load the app the problem must be on Play Store/Play Console side which makes your question an Android development/deployment question which is unfortunately considered off-topic here as we concentrate on Android from a user perspective.

Comment: Thanks, will post it on Stackoverflow instead

Comment: Have asked this question on the appropriate site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208902/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-play-store